# "many to many to many" relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a simple database of cosmetics. Each product may consist of multiple ingredients. Therefore it is a simple many to many relation and currently I have a database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `ingredients` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `ingredient_to_product` (
  `ingredient_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ingredient_id`, `product_id`),
  INDEX (`product_id`)
);
```

However, some ingredients can have many different names. For example: "LINALOOL ESSENTIAL OIL", "LINALYL ALCOHOL" and "3,7-DIMETHYL-1,6-OCTADIEN-3-OL" refers to the same ingredient.

When I am presenting one product, I would like to keep ingredient name as on product label. So in case of one product it will be "LINALYL ALCOHOL" and in case of another product it may be something other, but referring to identical ingredient.

Now I would like to query database for all names of the product by specifying one of its names or by its ID, however how one ID could refer to many names? Do I have to keep two tables: one for specific ingredient in general and another table just for names (relation many names to one ingredient)? Is there any better way?

Comment: The synonym table is the best method.

Comment: I would remove the name from the product table, then create a table nearly identical to your ingredient_to_product table called product_to_name containing a composite primary key between your the product_id and name. You can also add a third column that indicates which one the preferred name(s) is/are.

Answer (score 2):

**`Ingredients`**

- `ID` (int) (pkey) (ai)
- `Name` (varchar)

**`Synonyms`**

- `ID` (int) (pkey) (ai)
- `IngredientID` (int) (foreign key maps to: `Ingredients.ID`)
- `Name` (varchar)
- `Flag` (optional; sample values: `IUPAC Name`, `Common Name`, `Spanish Name`, ...)

---

So yes, for the rules you described, you will at minimum have a primary name, and then a synonym table using the `Ingredients.ID`

I also introduced a `Flag` field so that you can programmatically choose when to use a synonym rather than just hard-coding it all the time. For example, if you're listing a product flagged as an `industrial chemical`, it would be programmed to pull the `IUPAC`* name

*IUPAC refers to conventions for naming chemicals, and is used by professional chemists almost always, but almost never used in consumer supermarkets: http://www.chem.uiuc.edu/GenChemReferences/nomenclature_rules.html

Comment: Yes, a synonym table was the first to come to my mind, too. You'd have to change `ingredient_to_product` to `synonym_to_product`, though. (You could also design the synonym table differently, such as to have multiple ingredient records still, that you simply group with synonym records. It's a matter of personal preference what model to choose.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the good news is that one name cannot be used for multiple different ingredients, right?

So yes, you probably need an "ingredient name" table, something like

```
`name` TEXT NOT NULL,
`ingredient_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

(I'd probably just use name as the PK here, but if your design calls for always using surrogates then also add `ingredient_name_id` I guess...)

And then the details of the `ingredient` (except name) would still go in ingredient table.  (You *could* keep a default name in the ingredient table as well, but I wouldn't.  If you need that concept, I'd consider adding a "default flag" to the ingredient name table or something like that.)

Since you want to know the name used for each ingredient by a given product, you would replace your current "ingredient to product xref" with an "ingredient-name to product xref".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a separate table for other ingredient name/chemical names, etc. and have it connected with the product id so it can be used separately when needed, and to avoid having any NULL values in your main table.